# PHP - Output of file content with wrong chars

Tags: php, file, character-encoding, download

I am making a php script for download files, and there's a weird issue.

It results that I have a class A which is the one that contains the method for the download of the file, then I require that file using 'require_once' into a file called init.php, init.php is required by the main script that makes the instance of the class and the one that the user has to visit. init.php is the one that starts my system and loads it's configuration.

Ok, class works fine, BUT the problem comes when the file makes an output for the file target content.

This is the method of my class:

```
public function descargar ($nombreDescarga = null) 
{
    if ($this->id === null || $this->formato === null || $nombreDescarga === null || 
        gettype($nombreDescarga) != "string" || strlen($nombreDescarga) == 0) 
    {
        return 1;
    }

    $ruta = RUTA_SISTEMA . "/" . RUTA_ASIGNACIONES . "/asign-" . $this->id . "." . $this->formato;
    $tamano = @filesize($ruta);

    /**
    * Comprobamos si el archivo existe.
    */

    if ($tamano === false) 
    {
        return 2;
    }

    /**
    * Saneamos el nombre de salida del archivo.
    */

    $nombreDescarga = Framework\sanearNombreArchivo($nombreDescarga . "." . $this->formato);

    /**
    * Colocamos los headers necesarios.
    */

    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . $nombreDescarga);
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . $tamano);

    /**
    * Abrímos el archivo y lo enviamos al navegador.
    */

    $contenido = @file_get_contents($ruta);

    if ($contenido === false) 
    {
        return 3;
    }

    echo $contenido;

    return 0;
}
```

Ok, this is the usual way to download a file, put the headers, and then output the file content (the rest is pure validation) BUT when file gets downloaded the content of the file instead of being:

```
ÈFÃË‹Átí#ª6˜²"wÇ9Ê´ÀÄ:0t
```

Results being:

```
�F�ˋ�t�#�6��"w�9����:0t
```

I've tried by making a separated script for the the download, and works perfect, file gets downloaded with correct characters, I just figured out that problem comes when I include the init.php file, it seems that there is double charset or something and file ends messed up. I noticed that the function file_get_contents returns the right string content because I tried by saving the string into a new file with the fopen and fwrite functions, the file was copied with the right characters.

In my opinion it's a problem with the charset of main script that will make the output, I tried by setting "header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream; charset=UTF-8');" in my method with no luck.

It's the first time that I've seen something like this, it's very weird, any suggestion will be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Which editor are you using; with Sublime Text you can check the file enconding o save file as utf8...código con comentarios FTW!!

Comment: I use Notepad++ with the file codified in ANSI

Comment: But are all your php files with the same enconding??. The init.php file is also in Ansi??

Comment: Yes, all the required files are in ANSI :/

Comment: Maybe if you use the php function utf8_encode or utf8_decode

Comment: I did, but it's not accurate, I've problems with some characters when I use that function..

Answer (score 0):

Fixed!!!

The problem was the next:

In my init.php file I was requiring more files, and one of them (a file called CONFIG.class.php) had UTF-8 encoding, I really though that all the files were enconded in ANSI (yes, they were except for this one), then I changed the file encoding with Notepad++ to ANSI and voila! It worked..

Thank's to everyone for the suggestions :)